# jQuery load php file as text?

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to load a php file as text with jquery?

```
$('#loader').load('somefile.php', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

This always interprets/execute the php file but I'm looking for a way to only load it as text, without to resort to renaming my php file as .txt 
Is it possible?
Cheers

Comment: its not possible, because the webserver will interpret the request as an executable and thus pass the requested file and arguments to the php process

Comment: Just get rid of the php tags <?php ?> then it should render as text. Unles you need that file to run as php because then your screwed

Comment: Nicholas, yup that works for me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without making any server side modification. The web server will always interpret the php file and return the output. However does not matter what solution you find it'll be very dangereous since you'll be dumping content of your php file to public.

Possible solutions with server side modifications:

- Create a PHP file that dumps the content of a file, which name is specified by a url argument
- Rename the file (I know the op does not want this, just included since it's an option)
- As @nicholas-young suggested, get rid of the PHP tags.

I'm not sure why you need this type of need but I want to emphasize that this might not be a good idea in most of the cases since you'll be make a working PHP file available to public. If you can explain more why you need this we might offer better solutions.

Update:
Create a dumper.php that requires authorization and call this file from the javascript side with passing the filename that you want to be dumped as a parameter (dumper.php?file=index.php)

```
echo file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is of course not possibile.

`.load` will make an HTTP request to `yourwebsite.com/somefile.php` hence you will obtain the result of your script not the PHP code inside it.

If you really need the raw code inside your javascript as a string you should output it from the php itself:

```
<script>
var yourCode = <?=json_encode(file_get_contents('somefile.php')) ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

NO! Would be a major security problem if possible. The header will not matter. If making request towards php file, it will execute prior to delivery.

Use some parameter to print out contents from file instead. But do it in the file itself.